# NullPointerException exception when using Flink's leftOuterJoinLateral in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to follow [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/udfs.html#table-functions) and create a Table Function to "flatten" some data. The Table Function seems to work fine when using the `joinLateral` to do the flattening. When using `leftOuterJoinLateral` though, I get the following error. I'm using Scala and have tried both Table API and SQL with the same result:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null result cannot be stored in a Case Class.

Here is my job:

```scala
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.StreamTableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.functions.TableFunction

object example_job{
  // Split the List[Int] into multiple rows
  class Split() extends TableFunction[Int] {
    def eval(nums: List[Int]): Unit = {
      nums.foreach(x =>
        if(x != 3) {
          collect(x)
      })
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment()
    val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    val splitMe = new Split()

    // Create some dummy data
    val events: DataStream[(String, List[Int])] = env.fromElements(("simon", List(1,2,3)), ("jessica", List(3)))
    
    val table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(events, 'name, 'numbers)
      .leftOuterJoinLateral(splitMe('numbers) as 'number)
      .select('name, 'number)
    table.toAppendStream[(String, Int)].print()
    env.execute("Flink jira ticket example")
  }
}
```

When I change `.leftOuterJoinLateral` to `.joinLateral` I get the expected result:

```scala
(simon,1)
(simon,2)
```

When using the `.leftOuterJoinLateral` I would expect something like:

```scala
(simon,1)
(simon,2)
(simon,null) // or (simon, None)
(jessica,null) // or (jessica, None)
```

Seems like this might be a bug with the Scala API? I wanted to check here first before raising a ticket just in case I'm doing something stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Flink per default does expect that all fields of a row are non-null. That's why the program fails when it sees the `null` result from the outer join operation. In order to accept `null` values, you either need to disable the null check via

```
val tableConfig = tableEnv.getConfig
tableConfig.setNullCheck(false)
```

Or you must specify the result type to tolerate null values, e.g. specifying a custom POJO output type:

```
table.toAppendStream[MyOutput].print()
```

with

```
class MyOutput(var name: String, var number: Integer) {
  def this() {
    this(null, null)
  }

  override def toString: String = s"($name, $number)"
}
```

Comment: For some reason when update do `tableConfig.setNullCheck(false)` the result becomes: (simon,1)(jessica,-1)(simon,2)?? I'm thinking the best bet is to return an Option[Int] from the UDTF instead of not returning anything.

Comment: That's because an `Int` cannot be `null`.

Comment: Oh yep okay I get that now thanks. But I would expect (simon,1) (simon,2) (simon,-1) (jessica,-1) right? There is still a missing Simon record or am I not understanding the left outer lateral join?

Comment: I think the result is correct since the `leftOuterJoinLateral` call joins each row against the result of the specified table function. In your case the table function applied to `(simon, List(1,2,3))` will produce `(1), (2)` and, hence, the result is `(simon, 1)`, `(simon, 2)`. For `(jessica, List(3))`, the table function produces `None` and, hence, the result is `(jessica, -1/null)`. I guess the documentation could be more explicit that the table functions result is only joined against its input row.

Comment: Thanks Till, I think I get it now. I thought that each individual record returned from the table function was joined back to the input row but as you said it looks like the whole table is joined instead. Thanks for helping me understand it better!